# Unix tools for plotting 2D graphs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, charts

What are the available Unix commands for plotting a 2D graph on Mac OS X? XMGRACE, [GRACE](http://plasma-gate.weizmann.ac.il/Grace/) don't work on my laptop.

Can I download these packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile Grace yourself, or download the [MacPort](https://ports.macports.org/?search=grace&search_by=name) package. You will probably need Apple's developer tools for this.

---

[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is a well known graphing program and available as a MacPort and via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: Gnuplot works well. Thanks for the info, Daniel.